# Best practice booleans in java

Tags: java

Quick question,

Is this...

```
this.setPregnant(isPregnant = true);
```

...the same thing as this?

```
this.setPregnant(true);
```

Which one is better practice?

```
@ScheduledMethod(start = 3) 
public void mate() {
    if (this.isFemale == true) {
        Context context = ContextUtils.getContext(this);
        Geography<Agent> geography = (Geography)context.getProjection("Geography");
        Geometry geom = geography.getGeometry(this);
        // get coordinates of the female
        Coordinate femCoord = geom.getCoordinates()[0];
        List<Agent> males = new ArrayList<Agent>();
        //create an envelope around the female
        Envelope envelope = new Envelope (femCoord.x + 0.9, femCoord.x - 0.9, femCoord.y + 0.9, femCoord.y - 0.9);
        //get all the males around the female
        for(Agent male: geography.getObjectsWithin(envelope, Agent.class)) {
            if(male.isFemale != true)
                //add them to a list
                males.add(male);
        }

        //randomly choose one, set isPregnant to be true and move to his coordinates
        int index = RandomHelper.nextIntFromTo(0, males.size() -1);
        Agent mate = males.get(index);
        Context matecontext = ContextUtils.getContext(mate);
        Geography<Agent> mategeography = (Geography)matecontext.getProjection("Geography");
        Geometry mategeom = mategeography.getGeometry(mate);
        Coordinate mate = mategeom.getCoordinates()[0];

        this.setPregnant(isPregnant = true);
        // or this.setPregnant(true);

        moveTowards(mate);

        System.out.println("Female can now lay eggs...");

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the above one. Just an opinion. Much less readable.

Comment: No, without knowing what setPregnant does, the two could be doing different things. The first assigns true to isPregnant and then passes that value through to the method, where the second just passes true to the method....

Comment: @MadProgrammer Still its mixing assignment and operation.

Comment: @DamianNikodem no argument, did suggest that it should be used, just that they are the same thing

Comment: @MadProgrammer Actually we would code review this as having 2 items if the setPregnant method does not actually set the isPregnant field.

Comment: @DamianNikodem If you wanted the flag isPregnant to be set independently of setPregnant, then, as you say, isPregnant should be set first and then passed to setPregnant, but that's just guess work ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer also wondering where the makePregnant method is.

Comment: @MadProgrammer -- method added

Comment: @DamianNikodem -- method added

Answer (score 5):

No its not. they are different,
The first one sets the boolean value "isPregnant" to true and then passes it to the "setPregnant" method and that example is terrible terrible practice.

(The majority of corporate style guides usually have a line which states "One should never mix assignment and operations. It makes code harder to read." )

The second is clear (but does not do the assignment) One would assume that the setPregnant method does the assignment again (but one cannot be sure )

Answer (score 1):

Never saw syntax like the top one for a setter method. The bottom one is far more readable and practical, so avoid the other one.

Comment: The syntax is valid, but considered poor practice. (because its doing a assignment and then passing the parameter to the setPregnant method. ) The Poster may mistakenly believe that java supports named parameters (in ada a  call such as setPregnant(pregnant => true, hasBeenConfirmedByTest => true) can improve readability.

Comment: Ok. I was just never taught or aware of the first implementation. Also In the first one, wouldn't it be setting the same thing to true twice?

Comment: @brtballin In java such a feature does not exist at this current time (JDK8 being the current generation), although there are plenty of languages that support named parameters (C#, ada, objective C.. ) If you ment inline assignment then the reason why you have not seen it 'in  the wild' is because its really poor practice, but its legal to have a line of code such as "while ( (a = myMethod(c,b) ) > 0) "

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside the class that have the `isPregnant` attribute, you can just assign the **attribute directly**. No method call is needed.

```
isPregnant = true;
```